# Magento 2 customer custom attributes

Tags: magento-2.1, custom-attributes

I followed this tutorial to have customer custom attributes :

http://www.extensions.sashas.org/blog/magento-2-1-3-how-to-make-customer-attribute-update.html

which was working fine since I updated from Magento **2.1.7** to **2.1.9**.

The form is not working anymore.

The page reloads, but nothing happens, no error or success message and customer is not being registered.

When I delete `app/design/frontend/{theme_company}/{theme_name}/Magento_Customer/templates/form/register.phtml`, the registration works fine.

I also checked the new `vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/form/register.phtml` file, and saw no change in latest version.

The problem does not seem to come from

> app/design/frontend/{theme_company}/{theme_name}/Magento_Customer/templates/form/register.phtml

If I only copy

> vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/form/register.phtml

to

> app/design/frontend/{theme_company}/{theme_name}/Magento_Customer/templates/form/register.phtml

without making any changes, I have the same problem.

Looks like the file does not « connect » with files located in `app/code/Sashas/CustomerAttribute/` anymore .. ?

I tried to **setup:upgrade** and **setup:di:compile** after Magento update, but no change.

I can't seem to find any changes made in customer registration files in versions **2.1.8** or **2.1.9**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that after the update to 2.1.9, the custom register.phtml file was missing the form key.

I added

```
<?php /* @noEscape */ echo $block->getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?>
```

just after the  tag, and it's working fine.

Same change has to be made on the custom edit.phtml.